# Golang recursive crawler results in blocking state

Tags: go, concurrency, web-crawler

I am trying to make a crawler in Go that spawns X goroutines. Currently I'm spawning only one goroutine (workers=1) and I'm using a channel for sending to/reading from it. The desired outcome is to spawn a concrete number of workers which read jobs from a chan and each job can push more jobs to the chan without blocking the goroutine.

But for some reason now the goroutine is blocked and does not process recursive links. What can be the reason? How should I approach this problem?

```
const maxDepth = 1

type job struct {
    URL   string
    Depth int
}

type Crawler struct {
    jobs             chan job
    workers          int
    db               db.DB
    timeout          int
    imagesFolderName string
    visited          *sync.Map
    wg               *sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewCrawler(db db.DB, workers int, timeout int, imagesFolderName string) *Crawler {
    return &Crawler{
        jobs:             make(chan job),
        workers:          workers,
        db:               db,
        timeout:          timeout,
        imagesFolderName: imagesFolderName,
        visited:          &sync.Map{},
        wg:               &sync.WaitGroup{},
    }
}

func (c *Crawler) enqueue(j job) {
    c.wg.Add(1)
    c.jobs <- j
}

func (c *Crawler) Start(startingLinks []string) {
    if err := os.MkdirAll("apps/imagecrawler/"+c.imagesFolderName, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating image directory: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for i := 0; i < c.workers; i++ {
        go func() {
            for j := range c.jobs {
                c.runJob(j)
                c.wg.Done()
            }
        }()
    }

    for _, link := range startingLinks {
        c.enqueue(job{URL: link, Depth: 0})
    }
    c.wg.Wait()
    close(c.jobs)
}

func (c *Crawler) runJob(j job) {
    _, alreadyVisited := c.visited.LoadOrStore(j.URL, true)
    if alreadyVisited {
        return
    }

    pageCtx, pageCancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Minute*time.Duration(c.timeout))
    fmt.Println("Crawling URL", j.URL, "Depth:", j.Depth)
    resp, err := http.Get(j.URL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fetching error:", err)
        resp.Body.Close()
        pageCancel()
        return
    }
    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Reading body: ", err)
        resp.Body.Close()
        pageCancel()
        return
    }
    resp.Body.Close()

    if j.Depth >= maxDepth {
        pageCancel()
        return
    }

    links, err := extracter.ExtractLinks(pageCtx, b, j.URL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ExtractLinks Err", err)
        pageCancel()
        return
    }

    for _, link := range links {
        c.enqueue(job{URL: link, Depth: j.Depth + 1})
    }

    pageCancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually to enqueue recursive links in a separate goroutine which solves the problem partially. But, this creates/runs more goroutines. I want during the whole crawling process to have only X created and running goroutines. Are there alternative solutions? Can I achieve the same behaviour without spawning additional goroutines?

```
func (c *Crawler) runJob(j job) {
    // ...Same stuff

    for _, link := range links {
        c.wg.Add(1)
        --> go func(link string) {
            c.jobs <- job{URL: link, Depth: j.Depth + 1}
        }(link)
    }
    pageCancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all wait group should be spawned for your Goroutines, in your case the one that you are spawning.
Second, Goroutines do not work like workers, they are threads you spawn to do something on the background. if you want to make some kind of worker mechanizm you need to run a manager like a forever loop that is always listening on the channel and runs the `Enqueue` for each job deploys a Goroutine. if you increase the amount of Goroutines it would change the size of the bulk of jobs it could take at a time.

your enqueue function would look like something like this:

```
func Enqueue(ctx context.Context, job Job) {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        if err := processJob(job, ctx); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("job err, %v \n",err.Error()))
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: But how do you limit the numer of goroutines? I want to spawn 10 goroutines for example, initially, and let them process links. Also each job can add more links for processing due to the recursive crawling.

Comment: You could use context to send a signal each time a goroutine is done, or just wait for them to finish before spawning 10 more. All your jobs go through the jobs channel so it shouldn't be a problem.